# JMeter jp@gc JSON/YAML Path Assertion for an array

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm trying to use `jp@gc - JSON/YAML Path Assertion`, when my Response Body is:

```
[
  {
      "label": "Alabama",
      "value": "AL"
  },
  {
      "label": "Alaska",
      "value": "AK"
  },
  {
      "label": "American Samoa",
      "value": "AS"
  },
  {
      "label": "Arizona",
      "value": "AZ"
  },
  {
      "label": "Arkansas",
      "value": "AR"
  },
  {
      "label": "California",
      "value": "CA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Colorado",
      "value": "CO"
  },
  {
      "label": "Connecticut",
      "value": "CT"
  },
  {
      "label": "Delaware",
      "value": "DE"
  },
  {
      "label": "District Of Columbia",
      "value": "DC"
  },
  {
      "label": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
      "value": "FM"
  },
  {
      "label": "Florida",
      "value": "FL"
  },
  {
      "label": "Georgia",
      "value": "GA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Guam",
      "value": "GU"
  },
  {
      "label": "Hawaii",
      "value": "HI"
  },
  {
      "label": "Idaho",
      "value": "ID"
  },
  {
      "label": "Illinois",
      "value": "IL"
  },
  {
      "label": "Indiana",
      "value": "IN"
  },
  {
      "label": "Iowa",
      "value": "IA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Kansas",
      "value": "KS"
  },
  {
      "label": "Kentucky",
      "value": "KY"
  },
  {
      "label": "Louisiana",
      "value": "LA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Maine",
      "value": "ME"
  },
  {
      "label": "Marshall Islands",
      "value": "MH"
  },
  {
      "label": "Maryland",
      "value": "MD"
  },
  {
      "label": "Massachusetts",
      "value": "MA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Michigan",
      "value": "MI"
  },
  {
      "label": "Minnesota",
      "value": "MN"
  },
  {
      "label": "Mississippi",
      "value": "MS"
  },
  {
      "label": "Missouri",
      "value": "MO"
  },
  {
      "label": "Montana",
      "value": "MT"
  },
  {
      "label": "Nebraska",
      "value": "NE"
  },
  {
      "label": "Nevada",
      "value": "NV"
  },
  {
      "label": "New Hampshire",
      "value": "NH"
  },
  {
      "label": "New Jersey",
      "value": "NJ"
  },
  {
      "label": "New Mexico",
      "value": "NM"
  },
  {
      "label": "New York",
      "value": "NY"
  },
  {
      "label": "North Carolina",
      "value": "NC"
  },
  {
      "label": "North Dakota",
      "value": "ND"
  },
  {
      "label": "Northern Mariana Islands",
      "value": "MP"
  },
  {
      "label": "Ohio",
      "value": "OH"
  },
  {
      "label": "Oklahoma",
      "value": "OK"
  },
  {
      "label": "Oregon",
      "value": "OR"
  },
  {
      "label": "Palau",
      "value": "PW"
  },
  {
      "label": "Pennsylvania",
      "value": "PA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Puerto Rico",
      "value": "PR"
  },
  {
      "label": "Rhode Island",
      "value": "RI"
  },
  {
      "label": "South Carolina",
      "value": "SC"
  },
  {
      "label": "South Dakota",
      "value": "SD"
  },
  {
      "label": "Tennessee",
      "value": "TN"
  },
  {
      "label": "Texas",
      "value": "TX"
  },
  {
      "label": "Utah",
      "value": "UT"
  },
  {
      "label": "Vermont",
      "value": "VT"
  },
  {
      "label": "Virgin Islands",
      "value": "VI"
  },
  {
      "label": "Virginia",
      "value": "VA"
  },
  {
      "label": "Washington",
      "value": "WA"
  },
  {
      "label": "West Virginia",
      "value": "WV"
  },
  {
      "label": "Wisconsin",
      "value": "WI"
  },
  {
      "label": "Wyoming",
      "value": "WY"
  }
]
```

Here is how is use the JSON/YAML Path Assertion:
[image: Assert JSON Path exists]

but I'm getting Assertion failure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following setup should work for you:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [The New JSON/YAML Plugin - Using YAML in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-json-yaml-plugin-using-yaml-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) ( jp@gc - JSON/YAML is deprecated)

JSON start with array so use JSON Path

```
$.[0].label
```

You can also uncheck `Match as regular expression`